# Android, how can i show an image from Internet as ActionBar Logo?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I need to show the image of the user for my chat application, i have the URL and i need to set it as ActionBar Logo, how can i achieve that?

Right now i'm doing this:

```
imagen = i.getStringExtra("imagen");

String logo[] = imagen.split("/");

String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/GettfordCommunity/"+logo[7];
Log.i("foto =>", pathName);
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);

actionBar.setLogo(bd);
```

and in the Log i have the right path

```
foto => /mnt/sdcard/GettfordCommunity/1380141946.jpg
```

But is not showing the image in the ActionBar.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the flag for using the logo:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions( DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
```

and use this for preserving display options:

```
setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

or else use the drawable to set the icon:

```
actionBar.setIcon(bd);
```

you should be good to go....

Comment: I'd probably use `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);` instead, as it will preserve the current display options.

Comment: Excellent point - depending on the situation, that should have been included (edited the response - thx)

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, i just missed DISPLAY_USE_LOGO